# Using 'diff' command over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access, diff

If I have a folder with several files on my computer, and a copy of the same folder on a remote server, is it possible to run 'diff' through ssh so I can see the differences between my copy and the one on the remote server? Ideally, I'd like to see if there are any additional/less files in either copy of the folder and then check to see if the individual files themselves have any differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see if there are any additional/less files in either copy of the folder

```
diff -y <(ssh user@remote_server 'ls -1aR /remote_folder/') <(ls -1aR /local_folder/)
```

Answer (score 3):

`diff` only works with local files. You might use `scp` or `rsync` to copy the files to a local directory and compare it with `diff`, or you can use something like `sshfs` to mount a remote directory to a local one and compare it with the second one.

For a single file, you can use `ssh` and `diff`:

```
ssh user@machine cat remote-file | diff - local.file
```

Comment: Is there no ssh equivalent of diff? This would work... but it seems to me that someone else would have wanted the same thing, and hopefully done it. :P Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to find which files differ is to use rsync, as described in https://serverfault.com/a/16665/317052. Use

```
rsync -anicu  . user@remote_host:directory/
```